# Using counters within parallelize

Tags: parallelization

I am running a lengthy do loop and I wish to use `Parallelize` so that multiple kernels are used.  What I do in the loop is update a set of counters that report the final results.  The counters do not work when using `Parallelize`.  How can I fix this if possible.  Here is some sample code

```
Ncases=0; NS5=0; NA5=0; NF20=0; ND5=0; NC5=0; Nreducible=0; Nirreducible=0; 
Parallelize[Do[Ncases++; test=x^5+rx^3+sx^2+t(x+1); 
If[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[test],Nirreducible++;group=QuinticGaloisGroup[test]; 
If[group==SymmetricGroup[5],NS5++]; If[group==AlternatingGroup[5],NA5++]; 
If[group==MetacyclicGroup[20],NF20++]; If[group==DihedralGroup[10],ND5++]; 
If[group==CyclicGroup[5],NC5++],Nreducible++],{r,-10,+10},{s,-10,+10},{t,-10,+10‌​}]];
```

Where `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` returns true if the polynomial is reducible.  The function `QuinticGaloisGroup` determines the Galois group.  So using a generic polynomial as the test polynomial I am counting the cases.  The counters are not being incremented.  I have many examples like this where the calculation times becomes hours and days.

Comment: Please give skeleton example code so we can help.

Comment: Ncases=0;
NS5=0;
NA5=0;
NF20=0;
ND5=0;
NC5=0;
Nreducible=0;
Nirreducible=0;
Parallelize[Do[Ncases++;
test=x^5+r*x^3+s*x^2+t(x+1);
If[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[test],Nirreducible++;group=QuinticGaloisGroup[test];
If[group==SymmetricGroup[5],NS5++];
If[group==AlternatingGroup[5],NA5++];
If[group==MetacyclicGroup[20],NF20++];
If[group==DihedralGroup[10],ND5++];
If[group==CyclicGroup[5],NC5++],Nreducible++],{r,-10,+10},{s,-10,+10},{t,-10,+10}]];

Comment: In the sample code IrreduciblePolynomialQ returns true if the polynomial is reducible and QuinticGaloisGroup return the quintic Galois group of the polynomial.  Then I count the cases of the five possible groups.  This is an example of generic polynomials.

Comment: This example takes about 20 seconds to run.  Set the do loop parameters to 100 or more then calculation times is hours and days.

Comment: @LorenzHMenke Please update your question with your code, don't put it as a comment.

Comment: Look up `SetSharedVariable`. Also make sure there are no/little side-effects that are harmful to performance of your parallelization

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If my answer does not help you, could you indicate what needs to be address?  Thanks.

Comment: Using any kind of counters and procedural code (loops, gotos etc.) does usually not play well with parallelization. Before commiting serious effort into working parallelization into your current code you might want to look into reformulating your program in a functional way (see [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) which makes concurrency/parallelization easy )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update: It might be more convenient to use [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) instead of lists of rules, if you have V10.*

Instead of trying to tally the result from within the kernels, return a data structure indicating what should be incremented.  Then total the results after the parallel computations have been completed.

Since you did not supply complete code, I made up a simple `QuinticGaloisGroup` function for proof of concept.

```
Clear[NS5, NA5, NF20, ND5, NC5, Nreducible, Nirreducible];
groups = {NS5, NA5, NF20, ND5, NC5, Nreducible, Nirreducible};
QuinticGaloisGroup[t_] := {SymmetricGroup[5],
    AlternatingGroup[5],
    MetacyclicGroup[20],
    DihedralGroup[10],
    CyclicGroup[5]}[[Mod[Hash[{r, s, t}], 5, 1]]];
res = ParallelTable[
   With[{test = x^5 + r x^3 + s x^2 + t (x + 1)},
    If[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[test],
     Association@                      (* remove this line, if version is below V10 *)
      Join[{Nirreducible -> 1},
       Switch[QuinticGaloisGroup[test],
        SymmetricGroup[5], {NS5 -> 1},
        AlternatingGroup[5], {NA5 -> 1},
        MetacyclicGroup[20], {NF20 -> 1},
        DihedralGroup[10], {ND5 -> 1},
        CyclicGroup[5], {NC5 -> 1},
        _, {}]
       ],
      {Nreducible -> 1}]
     ],
   {r, -10, 10}, {s, -10, 10}, {t, -10, 10}];
```

Then tally the results:

```
Merge[Flatten[res], Total]
(*
  <|Nirreducible -> 7971, NC5 -> 1633, NS5 -> 1633, NF20 -> 1524, 
    ND5 -> 1593, NA5 -> 1588, Nreducible -> 1290|>
*)
```

If not using `Association`:

```
Thread[groups -> Total[groups /. Flatten[res, 2] /. Thread[groups -> 0]]]
(*
  {NS5 -> 1633, NA5 -> 1588, NF20 -> 1524, ND5 -> 1593, NC5 -> 1633,
   Nreducible -> 1290, Nirreducible -> 7971}
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetSharedVariable[Ncases]`, but be aware that this is essentially a mutex that the master kernel must synchronize access to. This probably isn't a problem if the rest of the code in your loop is slow.

**Edit** A potential better solution is to do something like this after your `ParallelDo` has finished:

```
Total /@ Transpose@ParallelEvaluate[{Ncases, NS5, NA5, NF20, ND5, NC5, Nreducible, Nirreducible}]
```

... which will sum each kernel's local values for the iterators.

Comment: The QuinticGaloisGroup function is slow.

Comment: As long as `Ncases` isn't being read/written frequently, it's a safe approach. Try it!

Comment: I tried setting the SetSharedVariable[severl counters] and the results were slower by a factor of 10.  Now the primary function QuinticGaloisGroup evaluates at hundreds to thousands of times per second depending on the test function being evaluated.  Is this a potential cause of this longer total time taken?

Comment: I'm not following -- QuinticGaloisGroup evaluates more times now than before, thus slowing down total time? See also a new idea in my edited answer.